# Why is the output for hash_pbkdf2 (PHP) different than the .NET / C# implementation

Tags: c#, php, .net, pbkdf2, rfc2898

In a small project of mine i need to calculate the hash of a function.

I have a working example of PHP hash

```
$pass = "123456";
$mysalt = strrev($pass);
echo hash_pbkdf2('sha1', $pass, $mysalt, 1000, 32); //using the PHP inbuilt function

echo "</br>";
include_once('PasswordHash.php');
echo pbkdf2('sha1', $pass, $mysalt, 1000, 16);  //using external code
```

Both of them has same output : `523d904c8f2df96634d9eed3b444838e`

Now i need my code to be backward be compatible with C# generated as the password has will be verified by a PHP server. and the Request is to be sent by a C# application.

Here is what i tried : output = `8e59ead5f90c6af11cf80641d51c241c`

```
public static class Program
{
    public static string ReverseString(this string s)
    {
        char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        return new string(arr);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pass = "123456";
        byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass.ReverseString());


        //https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing/blob/master/PasswordHash.cs
        //was getting error salt not 8 byte,
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647481/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-the-php-pack-function
        salt = Pack(pass.ReverseString());
        var hash = PasswordHash.PBKDF2(pass, salt, 1000, 16);
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower());

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public static byte[] Pack(string salt)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms))
            {
                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
                bw.Write(data.Length + 4); // Size of ASCII string + length (4 byte int)
                bw.Write(data);
            }

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regardless of your current problem: the reversed password makes for a shitty salt. And Encoding.ASCII is problematic for any password including non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @Јοеу - yes, i know, but that is what i have to implement.

Comment: Rfc2898DeriveBytes is what you are looking for. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx

Comment: @PaulK - yes, but generated hash is differnt :(

Comment: 200 Bounty will be awarded one who helps with proper solution !

Comment: Deriving the salt from the password completely defeats the purpose of having salt.

Comment: @hobbs - yes i know, but i am just re-writing a part of PHP that forces such rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is with your salt. It is only 6 bytes long and `PHP` handles this different then your `c#` code. If you update the code to the following:

```
<?php
$pass = "1234567890";
$mysalt = strrev($pass);
echo hash_pbkdf2('sha1', $pass, $mysalt, 1000, 32);
?>
```

your output is: 42e8bfc7fc5fd4686915d49d5a29bc1e

Then adjust your `c#` code to:

```
var pass = "1234567890";
byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass.ReverseString());

//DISABLE YOUR PACK METHOD
//salt = Pack(pass.ReverseString());

var hash = PasswordHash.PBKDF2(pass, salt, 1000, 16);
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower());

Console.ReadKey();
```

The output is: 42e8bfc7fc5fd4686915d49d5a29bc1e

The difference comes from your `Pack` method, it randomly adds 4 bytes to the salt. You can see that easily in the inspector in VS.

[image: Salt inspector]

So the easy fix is to use a salt that has atleast 8 chars (minimum for `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` which is used by your `C#` code) and dont use your `Pack` method

If you look at the [<sup>*php docs*</sup>](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/hash_pbkdf2) there is a "Request for comments" that mentions that the salt must be atleast 8bytes (64bit). So using less leads to conflicts, like you already encountered.

**UPDATE**

Now if you realy want to use the less secure salt with <8 bytes, you can look at the following stackoverflow question [PBKDF2 implementation in C# with Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1046599/434949) for a c# version that doesnt require a minimum length.

Comment: Thnx for the answer, but just say that the password length is less than 8 chars, in that case how does PHP function is able to calculate hash if minimum of 8 bytes is needed ?

Comment: Its not required to create a hash, it is recommended and the native `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` method requires it. I updated my answer with a link to a valid `c#` implementation that does not require the minimal salt length.

Comment: i should have put more effort into search :P !

Comment: cant give bounty for next 13 hrs m8 !

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Pack method is not necessary, but it is necessary that your salt be at least 8 bytes.

```
$pass = "12345678";
$mysalt = strrev($pass);
echo hash_pbkdf2('sha1', $pass, $mysalt, 1000, 32); //using the PHP inbuilt function
```

This outputs `381dae25b08b6f141671c74715961b1b`.

This C# code provides the same output.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static string ReverseString(this string s)
    {
        char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        return new string(arr);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pass = "12345678";
        byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass.ReverseString());


        //https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing/blob/master/PasswordHash.cs
        //was getting error salt not 8 byte,
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647481/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-the-php-pack-function
        var hash = PasswordHash.PBKDF2(pass, salt, 1000, 16);
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower());

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

From your comments, it seems like you may be developing under requirements constraints. If you are not able to control the requirements around salt, you might look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3055856/1600964).

Comment: Why did you feel the need to provide the exact same answer again?

Comment: Hi Hugo. You did beat me to all but the link to the other implementation. I apologize that I did not see your answer before posting.

Comment: No problem, and it is correct afterall including the link I was editing in at the same time. So I guess +1 for the effort.

Comment: Thanks, Hugo. Maybe next time I'll be a bit quicker on the draw :-)